# How can I access dict key while using asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, binance

This is a simple program to retrieve candlestick data from Binance exchange for several pairs. I found out that it could be done with asyncio package.

```py
import websockets
import asyncio
import json
import pprint


async def candle_stick_data():
    url = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/" #steam address
    first_pair = 'xlmbusd@kline_1m' #first pair
    async with websockets.connect(url+first_pair) as sock:
    pairs = '{"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": ["xlmbnb@kline_1m","bnbbusd@kline_1m" ],  "id": 1}' #other pairs

    await sock.send(pairs)
    print(f"> {pairs}")
    while True:
        resp = await sock.recv()
        resp=json.loads(resp)
        pprint.pprint(resp)
        candle = resp['k']


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(candle_stick_data())
```

I am getting messages and changing type to dict with `json.loads(resp)`. My question is how can I access dict values because `candle = resp['k']` causes "Key error 'k'". I am new to asyncio maybe I don't need it at all to retrieve data for several pairs.

updated message screenshot

[image]

Comment: "I am getting messages".  What messages?

Comment: You are printing out `resp`, which is a very good thing.  Do you see a key `k` in that printout?

Comment: @Tim Roberts see the screenshot

Comment: @user15082198 I cleaned up some of the formatting in your post; please correct the code block's indentation if I made a mistake!

Comment: @TimRoberts check

Comment: Given that output, your error could not have occurred.  You're in an infinite loop here, so this is occurring over and over.  Remember, if the packet is large, `sock.recv()` won't get it all in one piece.  Perhaps you should check that the string ends with `}` before you try to decode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first incoming message really does not have 'k' key in dictionary.

I just added `if else` block to your code and it works well:

```py
import websockets
import asyncio
import json
import pprint


async def candle_stick_data():
    url = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/" #steam address
    first_pair = 'xlmbusd@kline_1m' #first pair
    async with websockets.connect(url+first_pair) as sock:
        pairs = '{"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": ["xlmbnb@kline_1m","bnbbusd@kline_1m" ],  "id": 1}' #other pairs

        await sock.send(pairs)
        print(f"> {pairs}")
        while True:
            resp = await sock.recv()
            resp = json.loads(resp)
            # get 'k' key value if it exits, otherwise None
            k_key_val = resp.get('k', None)  
            # easy if else block
            if not k_key_val:
                print(f"No k key found: {resp}")
            else:
                pprint.pprint(k_key_val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(candle_stick_data())
```